# sort the whole .csv based on the value in a certain column

Tags: text-processing, sort, csv

I have a `csv` file with different revenues. I want to sort the csv file on revenue from **high** to **low** value. I can't find how to do this in terminal without the use of python.

I don't want to use python.

I want to use something simple like `mlr`/`sed`/`awk`.

Input:

```
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.70,2020
company2,location2,-155921.70,-146.03,,,2020
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.90,2020
company4,location4,1050987.60,426317.61,,24.90,2021
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.30,2019
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.10,2020
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.30,2021
```

Output:

```
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.30,2021
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.30,2019
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.90,2020
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.10,2020
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.70,2020
company2,location2,-155921.70,-146.03,,,2020
company4,location4,1050987.60,426317.61,,24.90,2021
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
```

The revenue is empty to billions.

Hopefully someone can help me out with this one too

Comment: One thing to consider is whether you may have escaped values with commas or space, for example: `"ACME, Inc.","Coyote Road, LA",6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.30,2021`. If so, you may find that using Python's `csv` module (or other similar language) might be simpler than `sed` or `awk`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, you want to sort (stably) on revenue in numerically descending order, which sounds like it should be easy in Miller except that its [rules for null handling](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-main-null-data/#rules-for-null-handling) say:

> Records with one or more empty sort-field values sort after records with all sort-field values present

which means that they sort *first* in a descending sort:

```
$ mlr --csv sort -nr revenue file.csv
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.70,2020
company2,location2,-155921.70,-146.03,,,2020
company4,location4,1050987.60,426317.61,,24.90,2021
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.30,2021
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.30,2019
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.90,2020
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.10,2020
```

However using [then chaining](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-main-then-chaining/) it's straightforward to decorate-sort-undecorate with a key that assigns numerical 0 to empty revenues:

```
$ mlr --csv put '$key = is_empty($revenue) ? 0 : $revenue' \
    then sort -nr key then cut -x -f key file.csv
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.30,2021
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.30,2019
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.90,2020
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.10,2020
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.70,2020
company2,location2,-155921.70,-146.03,,,2020
company4,location4,1050987.60,426317.61,,24.90,2021
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
```

Comment: With Miller 6.8.0, you can use `sort -tr` to do "natural" sorting in descending order. I don't really know what "natural" means, but it seems to be doing what the user wants. See https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/#sort

Comment: @Kusalananda, about *natural sort*, see https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sorting/ which leads to https://github.com/facette/natsort which leads to http://davekoelle.com/alphanum.html (latter a dead link for me; it's mentioned at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). I sounds similar to zsh's numeric sort.

Answer (score 12):

Using `sort`:

```
cat input.csv | (sed -u 1q; sort -t, -r -n -k5)
```

The `sed -u 1q` is required to make the `sort` ignore the header. It basically means, process the 1st line and quit, then pass the remaining to `sort`. `-u` is short for `--unbuffered`, to tell `sed` not to buffer the lines.

Sort's flags:

- `-t,` to specify the delimiter to a comma.
- `-r` to make the sorted output descending. It's ascending by default.
- `-n` to sort numerically.
- `-k5` to sort the 5th key/column.

Demo:

```
$ cat input.csv | (sed -u 1q; sort -t, -r -n -k5)
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.30,2021
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.30,2019
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.90,2020
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.10,2020
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
company4,location4,1050987.60,426317.61,,24.90,2021
company2,location2,-155921.70,-146.03,,,2020
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.70,2020
```

Comment: With GNU sort, you can get the exact order shown by the OP by stopping the sort at key 5 (`-k5,5`) and adding the `-s` or `--stable` option

Answer (score 8):

Using mandatory POSIX tools available on all Unix systems:

```
$ { head -n 1; sort -t, -k5,5rn; } < file
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.30,2021
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.30,2019
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.90,2020
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.10,2020
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.70,2020
company2,location2,-155921.70,-146.03,,,2020
company4,location4,1050987.60,426317.61,,24.90,2021
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
```

See the comments below and [Can head read more input lines than it outputs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/750523/133219) for additional important information about the above script.

Comment: Is it really guaranteed that [`head`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html#tag_20_57) won't read ahead beyond the specified number of lines?  As far as I can see, only the output is specified, and `head` may use buffered I/O if it wishes, and consume more input.

Comment: I can see this issue. `( echo a; echo b; echo c ) | ( head -n1; cat )` returns just a single line `a` here. Termux on my phone, and also a Pi. FWIW

Comment: Well, looks this is a real problem as `{ head -n 1; cat; } < <(printf 'a\nb\nc\n')` (removing the subshells and pipe from @roaima's suggestion to narrow it down) only outputs `a` in cygwin. `printf 'a\nb\nc\n' | { head -n 1; cat; }` behaves the same way, but then `printf 'a\nb\nc\n' > file; { head -n 1; cat; } < file` produces the desired output. TIL... So, I THINK what I show in my answer is safe, but some other ways of reading the input may not be.

Comment: @EdMorton, POSIX requires `head` to leave the position within the file right after the last line it has output if the input is seekable, but leaves it unspecified when not (like for pipes). To be able to honour it for pipes, it would need to read one byte at a time (like `read` does) or peek at the contents of pipes without reading it to know where to stop reading and then read. IIRC, that's what ksh93's `head` builtin does. Few systems have peekable pipes these days. I've seen `head` implementations that don't honour the POSIX requirement for seekable files.

Comment: @EdMorton strikes me this is worth posting as a question

Comment: @roaima done, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/750523/133219

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thanks! roaima requested I post this as a question so I did, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/750523/133219, would you mind posting your comment as an answer there?

Answer (score 3):

The [duckdb db cli](https://duckdb.org/docs/installation/) is really a great tool, and it's simply SQL

```
duckdb -csv -c "select * from read_csv_auto('input.csv') order by revenue desc"
```

And you get

```
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.3,2021
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.3,2019
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.9,2020
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.1,2020
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.7,2020
company2,location2,-155921.7,-146.03,,,2020
company4,location4,1050987.6,426317.61,,24.9,2021
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'lines.head.put;  my @a = lines(); .put for @a.sort(-*.split(",")[4]);'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'lines.head.put; .put for lines.sort(-*.split(",")[4]);'  file
```

Briefly, the first `line` (header row) is read and immediately out`put`. Then the remainder of the lines are read. In the first example the value rows are stored in `@a` array. In the second example lines are sorted directly. The `sort` function takes a mapper, here sorting on lines that have been `split` on commas, and then taking the 5th column (zero-index = 4). Sorting is alphabetic so prepending `+` or `-` to the sort criteria forces numeric comparison (e.g. `.sort(+*.split(",")[4]`). The `-*.` negative sign is used to invert the sort order (descending instead of ascending).

Sample Input:

```
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.70,2020
company2,location2,-155921.70,-146.03,,,2020
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.90,2020
company4,location4,1050987.60,426317.61,,24.90,2021
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.30,2019
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.10,2020
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.30,2021
```

Sample Output:

```
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.30,2021
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.30,2019
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.90,2020
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.10,2020
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.70,2020
company2,location2,-155921.70,-146.03,,,2020
company4,location4,1050987.60,426317.61,,24.90,2021
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
```

---

*For more complex CSV files:*

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN); @a[1..*] = @a[1..*].sort(-*.[4]); csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT);'  <  file
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/lines
https://docs.raku.org/routine/split
https://github.com/Tux/CSV
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

MacOS has Ruby as a default and Ruby has a csv parser built in.

Here is a ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'tbl=CSV.parse($<.read, **{:headers=>true, :converters=>:all}).to_a
    header=tbl.shift
    puts header.to_csv
    idx=header.index("revenue")
    puts tbl.sort_by.with_index{|row, i| [row[idx].nil? ? 0 : -row[idx] ,i] }.
        map{|row| row.to_csv}
' file
```

Or you can use GNU awk (not the MacOS native awk) this way:

```
gawk -F, '
FNR==1{print; next}
{if (-$5 in a) {a[-$5 "_" FNR]=$0} else {a[-$5]=$0}}
END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
    for(i in a) print a[i] 
}
' file
```

Or regular MacOS awk and creating a pipe to `sort` (which is the fastest of these three):

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{print; next}
{print|"sort -t, -nk5,5rn"}' file
```

Any of those prints:

```
name,location,capital,profit-lost,revenue,employees,year
company8,location8,6161574.62,906591.96,124804038.64,51.3,2021
company6,location6,7965648.89,369947.14,64413602.44,103.3,2019
company3,location3,1873134.74,778424.56,13320152.32,16.9,2020
company7,location7,1531534.27,125750.94,3054307.36,12.1,2020
company1,location1,35527.19,-33226.25,,0.7,2020
company2,location2,-155921.7,-146.03,,,2020
company4,location4,1050987.6,426317.61,,24.9,2021
company5,location5,368506.18,11997.04,,,2019
```