# Uniquify first column and add numbers in second column in a file in linux

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I am collecting data from multiple files and dumping into a single summary file.

```
cat *files* | sort -u > final.rpt
a 1
a 5
a 6
b 2
b 3 
b 0
c 1
c 7
```

How can I uniquify based on string in first column and sum all the number in second column corresponding to that string.
For the example above expected output is :

```
a 12
b 5
c 8
```

Comment: Hello, did you try anything so far ? What error did you encounter or what didn't match the output you are trying to obtain ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `sort -u` on that input instead of just `sort`?

Comment: What should happen if two or more lines in the output of `cat` have e.g. `a 1`?

Answer (score 4):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' <input file>
```

The idea is to use associate arrays and sum there the value in second column

Comment: If input file is sorted, then an associate array is not really needed. But unless the OP's input file is absolutely gigantic and the memory is low, the optimization is hardly worth the effort.

Comment: @legolegs, with associate arrays is more strait method (i know :) ). And the speed is acceptable. On really huge file `sort` may get much longer (if do not reach memory constrains)

Answer (score 3):

Using `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -sW sum 2 -g 1 <file
```

This computes `sum` of second field `groupby` first field.

---

Using `Miller`:

```
$ mlr --nidx stats1 -a sum -f 2 -g 1 file
```

Assuming that the unsorted file has two fields only as in:

```
a 1
a 5
a 6
b 2
b 3
b 0
c 1
c 7
a 1
```

The following command first sorts the file then computes sum.

```
$ mlr --nidx uniq -f 1,2 then \
stats1 -a sum -f 2 -g 1 file
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here goes the solution with O(1) for memory usage:

```bash
awk 'NR>1 && $1!=prev {print prev, sum;sum=0} {sum+=$2;prev=$1} END {print prev, sum}' < final.rpt
a 12
b 5
c 8
```

Explanation: for each new record where $1 changes we print the result and reset the sum. We also print result at the end of the file, but not at the beginning (NR>1).
The code is somewhat cumbersome in comparison with the version with an associate array.

Comment: If you tweak it to `awk '$1!=prev{if (NR>1) print prev, sum; sum=0; prev=$1} {sum+=$2} END{if (NR>1) print prev, sum}'` then it won't need to assign a value to `prev` for every input line, just when necessary, and it won't print a single blank char if the input is empty. So it'll be slightly more efficient and slightly more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %h; 
             given .split(/\s/, 2, :skip-empty) -> ($k,$v) { %h{$k} += $v }; 
             END .say for %h.sort;'   file
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. You could consider preparing your input data by adapting the Raku answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/750561/227738) (sorting on a single column ***without*** uniquifying).

Code is called at the commandline with the `-ne` (linewise, non-autoprinting) flags. A hash `%h` is declared in a `BEGIN` block. In the body of the linewise loop, each line is `split` on whitespace into `2` pieces. The `:skip-empty` parameter is used so that blank column values will throw an error.

The two elements are assigned to temporary variables `$k` & `$v`, which are referred to inside the block. Within the block, each `$k` key is looked-up in the `%h` hash. The key is added to the hash if not found, and the `$v` second-column value is `+=` assigned and/or added to that key's value (i.e. values accumulate).  Here the `+=` operator solves a lot of problems as it is really shorthand for `%h{$k} = (%h{$k} // 0) + $v`.

Finally after all lines are read, the result is output in an `END` block.

Sample Input:

```
a 1
a 5
a 6
b 2
b 3
b 0
c 1
c 7
```

Sample Output (using `say`):

```
a => 12
b => 5
c => 8
```

To get tab-separated columns in the output, use `put` instead of `say`:

Sample Output (using `put`):

```
a   12
b   5
c   8
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Would `... | sort | uniq -c >final.rpt` work (instead of using `... | sort -u >final.rpt`) to collect the data?

Comment: `uniq -c` will count the occurrences, not sum the numbers after

Comment: With the question it was not quite obvious how the original files did look like.